# What on earth is version "5.1.30really5.0.75" of MySQL on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I'm trying to upgrade Ubuntu packages and see some strange names flying across the screen.

This package naming convention is throwing me off just a bit :-)

What is 5.1.30really5.0.75?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running, by the way?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like jaunty and karmic were using these to transition people from 5.0 to 5.1.  According to [Ubuntu's changelogs](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/m/mysql-dfsg-5.0/mysql-dfsg-5.0_5.1.30really5.0.83-0ubuntu3/changelog) these packages were mostly backports from Debian unstable, since Debian stable is still using 5.0.  There's a lot of stuff in their changelogs and a lot of noise on various packages' bugtrackers from around that time about the change from [libmysqlclient15 -> libmysqlclient16](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-dfsg-5.0/+bug/316280), which looks like [it didn't get completed until lucid](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-dfsg-5.0/+bug/563053).